How to define 6 palettes in Angular Material 3?
I have Angular Material 3 project and I need to define 6 custom palettes:
primary
secondary
tertiary
error
neutral
neutral-variant

But, according to docs, when defining a theme, in color section we can only define 2 options: primary and tertiary.
How to add all 6 palettes to a theme?

There is no inputs to supply for secondary, etc. You can check the source code
I would suggest the below approach to theming your code.
First create a custom m3 theme, then you will be asked a bunch of questions.
ng generate @angular/material:m3-theme

After answering that, you will get a file, that contains the color definitions for each of the types you want. Style these as per your requirements. It will look like shown below.
// This file was generated by running 'ng generate @angular/material:m3-theme'.
// Proceed with caution if making changes to this file.

@use 'sass:map';
@use '@angular/material' as mat;

// Note: Color palettes are generated from primary: #eeeeee, secondary: #fefefe, tertiary: #000000, neutral: #ffffff
$_palettes: (
  primary: (
    0: #000000,
    10: #001f24,
    20: #00363d,
    25: #00424a,
    30: #004f58,
    35: #005b66,
    40: #006874,
    50: #008391,
    60: #00a0b0,
    70: #22bccf,
    80: #4fd8eb,
    90: #97f0ff,
    95: #d0f8ff,
    98: #edfcff,
    99: #f6feff,
    100: #ffffff,
  ),
  secondary: (
    0: #000000,
    10: #001f24,
    20: #00363d,
    25: #00424a,
    30: #004f58,
    35: #005b66,
    40: #006874,
    50: #008391,
    60: #00a0b0,
    70: #22bccf,
    80: #4fd8eb,
    90: #97f0ff,
    95: #d0f8ff,
    98: #edfcff,
    99: #f6feff,
    100: #ffffff,
  ),
  tertiary: (
    0: #000000,
    10: #3e001d,
    20: #5e1133,
    25: #6c1d3e,
    30: #7b2949,
    35: #893455,
    40: #984061,
    50: #b6587a,
    60: #d57193,
    70: #f48bae,
    80: #ffb1c8,
    90: #ffd9e2,
    95: #ffecf0,
    98: #fff8f8,
    99: #fffbff,
    100: #ffffff,
  ),
  neutral: (
    0: #000000,
    4: #000c0e,
    6: #001316,
    10: #001f24,
    12: #002429,
    17: #002f35,
    20: #00363d,
    22: #003b42,
    24: #004047,
    25: #00424a,
    30: #004f58,
    35: #005b66,
    40: #006874,
    50: #008391,
    60: #00a0b0,
    70: #22bccf,
    80: #4fd8eb,
    87: #81e9f9,
    90: #97f0ff,
    92: #aef3ff,
    94: #c5f6ff,
    95: #d0f8ff,
    96: #daf9ff,
    98: #edfcff,
    99: #f6feff,
    100: #ffffff,
  ),
  neutral-variant: (
    0: #000000,
    10: #141d1f,
    20: #293234,
    25: #343d3f,
    30: #3f484a,
    35: #4b5456,
    40: #576062,
    50: #6f797a,
    60: #899294,
    70: #a3adaf,
    80: #bfc8ca,
    90: #dbe4e6,
    95: #e9f2f4,
    98: #f2fbfd,
    99: #f6feff,
    100: #ffffff,
  ),
  error: (
    0: #000000,
    10: #410002,
    20: #690005,
    25: #7e0007,
    30: #93000a,
    35: #a80710,
    40: #ba1a1a,
    50: #de3730,
    60: #ff5449,
    70: #ff897d,
    80: #ffb4ab,
    90: #ffdad6,
    95: #ffedea,
    98: #fff8f7,
    99: #fffbff,
    100: #ffffff,
  ),
);

$_rest: (
  secondary: map.get($_palettes, secondary),
  neutral: map.get($_palettes, neutral),
  neutral-variant: map.get($_palettes,  neutral-variant),
  error: map.get($_palettes, error),
);
$_primary: map.merge(map.get($_palettes, primary), $_rest);
$_tertiary: map.merge(map.get($_palettes, tertiary), $_rest);

$light-theme: mat.define-theme((
  color: (
    theme-type: light,
    primary: $_primary,
    tertiary: $_tertiary,
  ),
));

Then finally, apply this theme to your project and it will get applied using the below code, so you can notice that tertiary styles certain palette types are discarded. So there is no need to specify this.
/// Defines an Angular Material theme object with color settings.
/// @param {Map} $config The color configuration
/// @return {Map} A theme object
@function define-colors($config: ()) {
  $err: config-validation.validate-color-config($config);
  @if $err {
    @error $err;
  }

  $type: map.get($config, theme-type) or light;
  $primary: map.get($config, primary) or palettes.$violet-palette;
  $tertiary: map.get($config, tertiary) or $primary;
  $system-variables-prefix: map.get($config, system-variables-prefix) or sys;
  sass-utils.$use-system-color-variables: map.get($config, use-system-variables) or false;

  @return (
    $internals: (
      theme-version: $theme-version,
      theme-type: $type,
      palettes: (
        primary: map.remove($primary, neutral, neutral-variant, secondary),
        secondary: map.get($primary, secondary),
        tertiary: map.remove($tertiary, neutral, neutral-variant, secondary),
        neutral: map.get($primary, neutral),
        neutral-variant: map.get($primary, neutral-variant),
        error: map.get($primary, error),
      ),
      color-tokens: m3-tokens.generate-color-tokens(
          $type, $primary, $tertiary, map.get($primary, error), $system-variables-prefix)
    )
  );
}


Can the values for tones in palettes come from css variables? (this might be a separate question, if needed)

@tlzg yes why not, try var(--some-var), do give green tick it the answer helps

I think there is another way of doing things. You can use createTheme from angular material to create a theme and use it.
You can do it something like this:
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { provideAnimations } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {
  provideThemeManager,
  defineColorPalette,
  createTheme,
  ThemePalette,
} from '@angular/material/theming';

// Define your custom color palettes
const primaryPalette = defineColorPalette('#006A6A');
const secondaryPalette = defineColorPalette('#4A6363');
const tertiaryPalette = defineColorPalette('#4B6079');
const errorPalette = defineColorPalette('#BA1A1A');
const neutralPalette = defineColorPalette('#191C1C');
const neutralVariantPalette = defineColorPalette('#3F4949');

// Create your custom theme
const customTheme = createTheme({
  density: 0,
  colorScheme: 'light',
  colors: {
    primary: primaryPalette,
    secondary: secondaryPalette,
    tertiary: tertiaryPalette,
    error: errorPalette,
    neutral: neutralPalette,
    'neutral-variant': neutralVariantPalette,
  },
});

@NgModule({
  imports: [MatButtonModule],
  providers: [
    provideAnimations(),
    provideThemeManager(customTheme),
  ],
})
export class AppModule { }

Then in order to use these colors, you can do this:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ThemePalette } from '@angular/material/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
  template: `
    <button mat-raised-button [color]="primaryColor">Primary</button>
    <button mat-raised-button [color]="secondaryColor">Secondary</button>
    <button mat-raised-button [color]="tertiaryColor">Tertiary</button>
    <button mat-raised-button [color]="errorColor">Error</button>
    <div [class]="'custom-element ' + neutralBackgroundClass">
      This div uses the neutral background color
    </div>
    <div [class]="'custom-element ' + neutralVariantBackgroundClass">
      This div uses the neutral-variant background color
    </div>
  `,
  styles: [`
    .custom-element {
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 5px 0;
    }
    .neutral-bg {
      background-color: var(--md-sys-color-neutral);
      color: var(--md-sys-color-on-neutral);
    }
    .neutral-variant-bg {
      background-color: var(--md-sys-color-neutral-variant);
      color: var(--md-sys-color-on-neutral-variant);
    }
  `]
})
export class ExampleComponent {
  primaryColor: ThemePalette = 'primary';
  secondaryColor: ThemePalette = 'secondary';
  tertiaryColor: ThemePalette = 'tertiary';
  errorColor: ThemePalette = 'error';

  neutralBackgroundClass = 'neutral-bg';
  neutralVariantBackgroundClass = 'neutral-variant-bg';
}

